# Do I have jailbreak my iPhone 3GS again after updating to iOS 5.1.1

Tags: ios, jailbreak

Before updating my 3GS to iOS 5.1.1, my phone was already jalibroken. After the update, i lost all those apps and do i have to jailbreak the phone again or is it still jailbroken? If so how do i get those apps back?

I am using Abisnthe 2.0 to jailbreak it but it is stuck in mid process and then i received an error from windows saying the program isn't responding and i had to close it. What could be a reason for that?

Answer (score 2):

If you updated with the official Apple update through iTunes, you're going to have to jailbreak again.

If you updated it using [redsn0w](http://www.coolestguyplanettech.com/upgrade-jailbroken-iphone-to-ios-5-and-preserve-baseband-with-redsn0w/) or another program, you would still be jailbroken.

If Absinthe is hanging, make sure you have the [latest version](http://absinthejailbreak.com/untethered-jailbreak-5-1-1-iphone-4s-4-3gs-absinthe-2-0/).  There have been two updates as of the time of this answer.

Comment: Thanks alot! which link is the actual download link? there are a few and I wanna know which one is the latest and updated one.

Comment: **For the Abisnthe

Comment: I think [this](http://absinthejailbreak.com/absinthe-v2-0-4-support-ipad-24-on-ios-5-1-1-now-available/) is the newest one.

Comment: This is the one that I downloaded and tried to Jailbreak. This time i received an error that said : "could not connect to lockdownd". Any ideas on what that could mean?

Comment: Why not accept this answer as yes and then ask the second more specific question about how to troubleshoot lockdownd. It's probably in the FAQ for the jailbreak software, but it's also on topic here to ask.

Comment: Read the first post, it was a two-part question.